# Android ItemizedOverlay scaling canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, google-maps-mobile

i am trying to scale pictures in a Android map itemizedOverlay,
i got it working to the point where i can see 10 pictures, i got zoomControle but nothing else really,

this is the MapItems class that extends ItemizedOverlay, optimizations is welcome

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MapItems extends ItemizedOverlay 
{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Context mContext;

    public MapItems(Drawable defaultMarker) 
    {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas,MapView mapView,boolean shadow) 
    {
        /*
        Log.d("MapAc", String.valueOf(mapView.getZoomLevel()));
        if(mapView.getZoomLevel() > 20)
        {
            Log.d("MapAc", "scaling up");
            canvas.scale(1.2f, 1.2f);
        }

        */

        super.draw(canvas,mapView,false);
    }


    public MapItems(Context context) 
    {
        super(boundCenterBottom(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon_clean))); 
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) 
    {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void clearOverlay()
    {
        mOverlays.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) 
    {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() 
    {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

     @Override
     protected boolean onTap(int index) 
     {
         /* ToDo
       OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
       AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
       dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
       dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
       dialog.show();
        */
       return true;
    }

}
```

i have been trying to scale in the draw method, using canvas.Scale, however this seems to redraw the canvas in another location, together with the old canvas"in its original size",
i am not sure if i am approaching this problem from the right angle, or if it is simply a matter of clearing the screen, i have been using a few days to figure this out, so a method to scale my pictures correct when zooming is VERY appreciated,

Comment: are you using the new Maps API?

Comment: Nope, the old one, didn't even notice there was one :S, should i reconsider shifting? how much is reusable?

Comment: Thats your first error. Use the new one. They really simplyfied a lot in the new stuff.

Comment: Nice, i will see to it, if no one comes along with a solution to this, i think you should post a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new MAPS API V2

[Blog article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html)

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97HLa739rXU&feature=g-user-u)

Comment: This is properly a valid solution, however for future readers, this is not so easy as you would properly think, i am now struggling to make it work in eclipse, there is not a lot of tutorials out there yet

Comment: Learning deprecated stuff is not the way to go either.

Comment: Bonus tip... if you got a older version of eclipse installed, this can course you trouble, please install the android sdk with eclipse, i got all kind of strange results using my old setup